# Draw performance profile figure in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab

[image]

what function should i use to draw the above performance profile of different algorithms, the running time data is from python implementation, stored in lists for different algorithm. Is there any build-in function in Python or Matlab to draw this kind of figure automatically? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like that in Python with Matplotlib using [step](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step) and [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

In Matlab you can use [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and [stairs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the performance of your algorithms in a list (if you are using Python) or in a matrix (Matlab) and then plot the results.

Matlab comes with several plot functions such as figure(), plot(), subplot() that you will need to draw those figures.

In Python you can use the third-party package [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org). By the way, Matplotlib gives you a MatLab like environment called [PyLab](http://wiki.scipy.org/PyLab) that tries to emulate Matlab commands.

Answer (score 0):

A Python function that draws these profiles which can be found, with instructions, [here](https://github.com/Jvanschoubroeck/performance-profiles-in-python).  After importing this function and generating a *Pandas DataFrame* object using your data (see instructions), the generation of the performance profile is easy.

A MATLAB script that draws performance profiles can be found [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~more/dfo/).

Answer (score 0):

I make simple performance charts, like those posed in the question, via Python scripts that rely on a Python module named leather. For example, within the following gist.github.com repository:
 https://gist.github.com/lhuemill/f1273291e5f5e85e4b42e5c7614e60ef

is a Python script, named permutations2x2_chart_results, which does this. By default, this script produces a chart using the SVG format.  A format that is directly supported by most of the popular web browsers and that are a vector versus bitmap graphic. Vector graphics tend to be a good choice for these types of performance graphs, in that the user can zoom into any portion of the results, to obtain more detail, without pixelation.